# NameError: Undefined

Tags: python, html, django, scope, initialization

I am working on a django project where I define a loop variable 'category' in an html file but it is not recognizing the variable. While all other variables working fine. Please look at the code and tell me if there is anything wrong.

```
    % for category in categories:
<div class="mobile-nav-item dropdown-item dropdown-nav-item toggle-category-sub-dropdown" 
  role="button" aria-label=${_("Options Menu")} aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-controls="${category.replace(' ','_')}">
  <a role="menuitem">${_(category)}</a>
  <div style="left:100%;top: -1px !important;width: max-content" class="dropdown-category-sub-menu hidden" aria-label=${_("More Options")} role="menu" id="${category.replace(' ','_')}" tabindex="-1">
    % for subject in subjectLists:
      %if category == subject['category']:
        <div class="mobile-nav-item dropdown-sub-item dropdown-nav-item"><a href="${reverse('about_course', args=[text_type(subject['id'])])}" role="menuitem">${_(subject['name'])}</a></div>
      %endif
    % endfor
  </div>
</div>
% endfor
```

Comment: Can you show your views.py, is there a categories in your context ?

Comment: no categories is just a list of strings I created it in html file.

Comment: Thanks a lot problem was in categories some values are not defined well.